# Getting values from JSON (Ajax) to array on server PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a question , because of their work needs to process JSON object by the PHP server and add it to the records in the database? How can I do this?

My JavaScript code:

```
xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("GET", "addPosition.php?Positions=" + JSON.stringify(positions), true);
xhttp.send();
```

PHP:

```
$data = $_GET['Positions']; 
$myArray = json_decode($data, true);
echo $myArray[0]['Symbol']; // Fetches the first ID
```

Comment: json_decode function in php?

Answer (score 0):

> Try This Code

**JQuery Code**

```
<script>
your_array=[];
your_array=JSON.stringify(your_array);
  $.ajax(
  {
          url:"results.php", // your php page
          method:"post",
          async:true,
           data:{'key':your_array},
         success:function(data)
           {
                    alert("data inserted");
           }
   });
</script>
```

**PHP Code**

```
<?php

$your_array= json_decode(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'key'));
echo "<pre>"
print_r($your_array);
// first of print your date then do your Database Operations
?>
```